# Modifying C message queue programs for use in Linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, message-queue

I've been working through this guide which outlines how to deal with message queues in Linux, and so far I haven't had any trouble.

http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html

However, I was wondering what I would have to do to modify the sample programs so that the message is delivered to a different recipient, depending on the message that is sent.
Eg: If message begins with the text 'URGENT', deliver to recipient A, else, deliver to recipient B.

I know I will need a second recipient class, but am not sure how to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I will need a second recipient class, but am not sure how to
>   implement this feature.

By *a second recipient class* you have got to mean a second message queue. Since the message queue identifier *`key`* in the sample programs is created by `key = ftok("kirk.c", 'B')`, an obvious choice for the second key is `keyurg = ftok("kirk.c", 'A')`, with which you `msgget()` the second queue (say `msqidurg`) in the sender as well as in the receiver. When it comes to sending a message:

```
        if (msgsnd(strncmp(buf.mtext, "URGENT", 6) ? msqid : msqidurg, &buf, len+1, 0) < 0)
            perror("msgsnd");
```